# getting error in dataframe replacement has 0 data has x

Tags: r

```r
out <-diallele1(dataframe = fulldial, male = "MALE", female = "FEMALE",  
 progeny = "TRT", replication = "REP", yvar = "YIELD" )

structure(list(FAMILY = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), TRT = c(11, 11, 
11, 12, 12, 12), FAMQC = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1), MALE = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), FEMALE = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), REP = c(1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3), AUDPC = c(3116.66666666667, 2983.33333333333, 3050, 
2483.33333333333, 1883.33333333333, 2183.33333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

while running these command i am getting the following error

```r
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "male", value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 192
```

somebody help me to fix this
thankyou

Comment: Welcome to SO, BonipasAntony! If you'd like anybody to be able to test your code, please make this question *reproducible* by including sample data. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `dput(head(fulldial))` in a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Thanks!

Comment: It also helps to know what non-base packages you're using. One might *infer* that you're using the `plantbreeding` package, but it's generally best to be explicit.